# How to overlay two ggplots using stat_summary() but different geom properties

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting the line chart with 95 confidence interval, however, I wish one condition's 95CI range can be visualized as ribbon rather than errorbar to show the range of upper and lower boundaries.

The code below shows the line chart with 95CI.

```
df1<-structure(list(subject = c("S11", "S11", "S11", "S11", "S11", 
"S12", "S12", "S12", "S12", "S12", "S12"), condition = c("placebo", 
"placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "Drug1", "Drug1", 
"Drug1", "Drug1", "Drug1", "Drug1"), Day = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Effect = c(-0.053, 0.02831, 
0.056, 0.450, 0.29, 0.011, 
-0.039, -0.01293, 0.042, 
-0.01568, 0.080)), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ggplot(df1,
             aes(x=Day,y=Effect,color= condition ,fill= condition)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="line",size=1.5,alpha=1)+
  stat_summary(fun.y ='mean',geom ="point", size = 1,alpha=0.8,show.legend = FALSE)+
  #geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=min.Uv, ymax=max.Uv), alpha=0.7,fill='yellow', colour=NA)+
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", fun.args = list(mult = 1),size=1)
```

The line that has been commented above (`geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=min.Uv, ymax=max.Uv)`) is using as visualization of 95CI of another condition.
I'm wondering whether there is a more efficient way to do so since the function of `fun.data = mean_cl_normal` is doing the same thing. 
So I implement the `fig1` with another figure that shares similar plotting grammar but different in `gemo='smooth'`. The main question it is possible to replace (`geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=min.Uv, ymax=max.Uv)`) by adding another plot with `gemo='smooth'` to show 95CI range?

```
df2<-structure(list(subject = c("S02", "S02", "S02", "S02", "S02"), 
    condition = c("Drug2", "Drug2", "Drug2", "Drug2", "Drug2"
    ), Day = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Effect = c(1.6592, 1.8384, 
    1.809, 1.807, 1.651)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

fig1+stat_summary(data=df2,aes(x=Day,y=Effect),
                  fun.data ="mean_cl_normal", geom = "smooth", , fun.args = list(mult = 1))
```

I got the overlaid line chart but the ribbon/smooth is missing. Any comment is much apprreciaated!

Comment: My recommendation would be to calculate all the necessary data outside of ggplot and then is it just for plotting.